# QueryWorkingSet includes invalid pages in its result

Tags: windows, winapi, memory-management, x86, access-violation

I'm currently using a 64-bit Windows 7 with I'm using Windows 7. I'm playing around with some [PSAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684884%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) (Process Status API) functions to learn a bit more about how Windows manages memory.

I noticed, however, that [`QueryWorkingSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684946%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) included entries from which I couldn't read (e.g. page 0, and you can't read `0x00000000`). When trying it on 64-bit, it became apparent why this was the case: `QueryWorkingSet` is bugged on 32-bit, as the addresses are truncated (hence the multiple page 0 entries).

Still, some entries returned by `QueryWorkingSet` on 64-bit are not accessible either. **Why does this obviously inaccessible memory show up as accessible? Is this another bug in `QueryWorkingSet`?** Furthermore, why don't any of the loaded modules show up in the result? Aren't they part of the working set? It is [explicitly stated on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that they are...

---

This is a small example program that uses SEH to try read the page, and reports the page when it is not readable (while `QueryWorkingSet` tells me it is):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char z;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned int counter;
    HANDLE thisProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION wsi_1, *wsi;
    DWORD wsi_size;

    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    wsi_1.NumberOfEntries = 0;
    QueryWorkingSet(thisProcess, (LPVOID)&wsi_1, sizeof(wsi));

#if !defined(_WIN64)
    wsi_1.NumberOfEntries--;
#endif
    wsi_size = sizeof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION)
             + sizeof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK) * wsi_1.NumberOfEntries;
    wsi = (PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),
        HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, wsi_size);

    if (!QueryWorkingSet(thisProcess, (LPVOID)wsi, wsi_size)) {
        printf("# Second QueryWorkingSet failed: %lu\n"
            , GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    for (counter = 0; counter < wsi->NumberOfEntries; counter++) {
        unsigned long long page = (unsigned long long)wsi->WorkingSetInfo[counter].VirtualPage;
        DWORD protection = (DWORD)wsi->WorkingSetInfo[counter].Protection;

        __try {
            if (*(char*)(page * si.dwPageSize) || TRUE) {
                z = (protection & 5) ? '-' : 'T';
            }
        } __except(GetExceptionCode() == STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION) {
            z = (protection & 5) ? 'F' : '-';
        }

        if (z == 'F') {
            printf("%p %p : %c%c%c%c%c %c\n"
                , (LPVOID)(page * si.dwPageSize)
                , (LPVOID)((page + 1) * si.dwPageSize)
                , protection & 16 ? 'G' : '-'
                , protection &  8 ? 'V' : '-'
                , protection &  4 ? 'w' : '-'
                , protection &  2 ? 'x' : '-'
                , protection &  1 ? 'r' : '-'
                , z
                );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The 32-bit version gives the following output:

```
7DBED000 7DBEE000 : --w-- F
7DBEE000 7DBEF000 : --w-- F
7DC00000 7DC01000 : --w-- F
80008000 80009000 : --w-- F
01080000 01081000 : --w-- F
01000000 01001000 : --w-- F
00000000 00001000 : --w-- F
7DA00000 7DA01000 : --w-- F
40001000 40002000 : --w-- F
003F7000 003F8000 : --w-- F
003FF000 00400000 : --w-- F
003BA000 003BB000 : --w-- F
00001000 00002000 : --w-- F
003B9000 003BA000 : --w-- F
40000000 40001000 : --w-- F
00006000 00007000 : --w-- F
00002000 00003000 : --w-- F
00000000 00001000 : --w-- F
0039A000 0039B000 : --w-- F
003A6000 003A7000 : --w-- F
003A8000 003A9000 : --w-- F
003AC000 003AD000 : --w-- F
00003000 00004000 : --w-- F
```

The 64-bit version gives this:

```
FFFFF6FB7DBED000 FFFFF6FB7DBEE000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB7DBEE000 FFFFF6FB7DBEF000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB7DC00000 FFFFF6FB7DC01000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB80008000 FFFFF6FB80009000 : --w-- F
FFFFF70001080000 FFFFF70001081000 : --w-- F
FFFFF70000000000 FFFFF70000001000 : --w-- F
FFFFF70001000000 FFFFF70001001000 : --w-- F
FFFFF7000107F000 FFFFF70001080000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB7DA0F000 FFFFF6FB7DA10000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB41FFF000 FFFFF6FB42000000 : --w-- F
FFFFF683FFFFF000 FFFFF68400000000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB40001000 FFFFF6FB40002000 : --w-- F
FFFFF680003FF000 FFFFF68000400000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB7DA00000 FFFFF6FB7DA01000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB40005000 FFFFF6FB40006000 : --w-- F
FFFFF68000A00000 FFFFF68000A01000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB40000000 FFFFF6FB40001000 : --w-- F
FFFFF68000000000 FFFFF68000001000 : --w-- F
FFFFF680003B9000 FFFFF680003BA000 : --w-- F
FFFFF68000001000 FFFFF68000002000 : --w-- F
FFFFF680003B6000 FFFFF680003B7000 : --w-- F
FFFFF680003B7000 FFFFF680003B8000 : --w-- F
FFFFF683FF7FA000 FFFFF683FF7FB000 : --w-- F
FFFFF683FF7EC000 FFFFF683FF7ED000 : --w-- F
FFFFF6FB41FFB000 FFFFF6FB41FFC000 : --w-- F
FFFFF680003F7000 FFFFF680003F8000 : --w-- F
FFFFF680003BA000 FFFFF680003BB000 : --w-- F
```

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are running this program on a 64-bit operating system.  Use QueryWorkingSetEx() instead.

Comment: I'm running this 32-bit program on a 64-bits Windows 7, so yes, WOW64 applies. Will port to QWSEx, but how does that not involve QWS itself? Isn't it to query specific addresses?

Comment: is it possible that both the read/write bit (4) is set and the read-only bit (1) is also set?  whats the output you get from your program?

Comment: Nope, only the r/w bit was set (I know 4+1 would imply copy-on-write). The offending pages all have --w-- flags.

Comment: I've tried QWSEx, and it doesn't return any information on the offending pages. But I can't use QWSEx to enumerate the pages in use, can I?

Comment: It seems entirely reasonable to me that a 32-bit process would have difficulty querying the working set of a 64-bit process. So don't do that. Are there any problems with querying working sets using a 64-bit process?

In UIforETW I disable working-set monitoring if you run a 32-bit version on 64-bit Windows for this reason.

Comment: @BruceDawson This problem occurs when the 32-bit process queries its own working set in a 64-bit environment.

Comment: @Rhymoid Thank you for the clarification. That does sound annoying. I guess the 64-bit parts of the process are affected, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that this is due to a shortcomings in the Native API. `K32QueryWorkingSet` uses `NtQueryVirtualMemory` pretty naively, assuming it can pass the results as-is to the caller. According to [this article](http://www.codemachine.com/article_x64kvas.html), the offending results refer to page tables and working set entries, which are perfectly readable from kernel space, but not directly accessible from user space.

A quick fix would be to clean up the result, so that addresses found below `MmSystemRangeStart` are considered valid. This value can only be read in kernel mode, so it has to be 'guessed' for user mode applications. For Windows 7 64-bit, it is `0xFFFF080000000000`. For 32-bit versions is a bit more tricky (due to 4GB tuning), but I'm not sure if the bug actually occurs there.