# What's the actual size of PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION buffer used in QueryWorkingSet function of PSAPI.h

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, psapi

I'd like to use the function `QueryWorkingSet` [available in PSAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-queryworkingset), but I'm having trouble to actually define the size of the buffer `pv`. Here is the code :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <iostream>


void testQueryWorkingSet()
{
    unsigned int counter;
    HANDLE thisProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION wsi, wsi2;

    GetSystemInfo(&si);
    QueryWorkingSet(thisProcess, &wsi, sizeof(wsi));

    DWORD wsi2_buffer_size = (wsi.NumberOfEntries) * sizeof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK);

    if (!QueryWorkingSet(thisProcess, &wsi2, wsi2_buffer_size))
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR CODE : " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        abort();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    testQueryWorkingSet();

    int* test = new int[1000000];

    testQueryWorkingSet();
}
```

I keep ending up with `abort()` being called and either an error code [24](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-) or [998](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--500-999-) during the first call to `testQueryWorkingSet()`. that I interpret respectively as : `wsi2_buffer_size` is too low and `wsi2_buffer_size` is too big.

Now I have no idea of the value this variable should take, I tried :

- counting everything including the `NumberOfEntries` field, that is `DWORD wsi2_buffer_size = sizeof(wsi.NumberOfEntries) + wsi.NumberOfEntries * sizeof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK);` => error 998;
- counting only the number of entries, that is the code given above => error 998;
- the size of the variable wsi2, that is `DWORD wsi2_buffer_size = sizeof(wsi2);` => error 24;

There has to be something I do not understand in the way we're supposed to use this function but I can't find what. I tried to adapt the code given [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285506/queryworkingset-includes-invalid-pages-in-its-result), that is :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <iostream>


void testQueryWorkingSet()
{
    unsigned int counter;
    HANDLE thisProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
    SYSTEM_INFO si;
    PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION wsi_1, * wsi;
    DWORD wsi_size;

    GetSystemInfo(&si);

    wsi_1.NumberOfEntries = 0;
    QueryWorkingSet(thisProcess, (LPVOID)&wsi_1, sizeof(wsi));

#if !defined(_WIN64)
    wsi_1.NumberOfEntries--;
#endif
    wsi_size = sizeof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION)
        + sizeof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK) * wsi_1.NumberOfEntries;
    wsi = (PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),
        HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, wsi_size);

    if (!QueryWorkingSet(thisProcess, (LPVOID)wsi, wsi_size)) {
        printf("# Second QueryWorkingSet failed: %lu\n"
            , GetLastError());
        abort();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    testQueryWorkingSet();

    int* test = new int[1000000];

    testQueryWorkingSet();
}
```

This code is working for only 1 call to `testQueryWorkingSet()`, the second one is aborting with error code 24. Here are the questions in brief :

1. How would you use `QueryWorkingSet` in a function that you could call multiple times successively?
2. What is representing the value of the parameter `cb` of [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-queryworkingset) given a `PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION`?

Comment: [Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043)

Comment: Also, `wsi` is a pointer, so `sizeof(wsi)` evaluates to the size of a pointer (i.e. 4 or 8). Though [QueryWorkingSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-queryworkingset) expects *"the size of the `pv` buffer, in bytes"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples are completely ignoring the return value and error code of the 1st call of `QueryWorkingSet()`. You are doing error handling only on the 2nd call.

Your 1st example fails because you are not taking into account the entire size of the `PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION` when calculating `wsi2_buffer_size` for the 2nd call of `QueryWorkingSet()`. Even if the 1st call were successful, you are not allocating any additional memory for the 2nd call to fill in, if the `NumberOfEntries` returned is > 1.

Your 2nd example is passing in the wrong buffer size value to the `cb` parameter of the 1st call of `QueryWorkingSet()`. You are passing in just the size of a single pointer, not the size of the entire `PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION`. Error 24 is `ERROR_BAD_LENGTH`. You need to use `sizeof(wsi_1)` instead of `sizeof(wsi)`.

I would suggest calling `QueryWorkingSet()` in a loop, in case the working set actually changes in between the call to query its size and the call to get its data.

Also, be sure you free the memory you allocate when you are done using it.

With that said, try something more life this:

```cpp
void testQueryWorkingSet()
{
    HANDLE thisProcess = GetCurrentProcess();

    PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION *wsi, *wsi_new;
    DWORD wsi_size;
    ULONG_PTR count = 1; // or whatever initial size you want...

    do
    {
        wsi_size = offsetof(PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION, WorkingSetInfo[count]);

        wsi = (PSAPI_WORKING_SET_INFORMATION*) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, wsi_size);
        if (!wsi)
        {
            printf("HeapAlloc failed: %lu\n", GetLastError());
            abort();
        }

        if (QueryWorkingSet(thisProcess, wsi, wsi_size))
            break;

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_BAD_LENGTH)
        {
            printf("QueryWorkingSet failed: %lu\n", GetLastError());
            HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, wsi);
            abort();
        }

        count = wsi->NumberOfEntries;
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, wsi);
    }
    while (true);

    // use wsi as needed...

    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, wsi);
}
```

Comment: Note, also, that the buffer size calculation is wrong. It ignores alignment requirements. Though, probably, inconsequential here, as it is over-allocating for 1 additional entry. Raymond Chen's link above explains how to properly determine the size.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks, I updated my example to reflect that

Comment: *You must initialize the NumberOfEntries field to the actual number of PSAPI_WORKING_SET_BLOCK buffers you have allocated* - this is wrong. we must not do this

Comment: use `HeapReAlloc` no sense, for what ? we not need copy previous content to new allocation. need use only `HeapAlloc`, not need zero memory (`HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY`) too

Comment: @RbMm I have updated my answer about the use of `NumberOfEntries`. I used `HeapReAlloc()` to avoid using `HeapFree()` on every loop iteration. It is not about preserving content, it is about letting the heap manager expanding the existing memory block in-place if it is able to.

Comment: yes, i understand for what you use `HeapReAlloc`m but anyway `HeapFree` is called internal for old block. so question what is take more time - free and acquire again heap lock, or copy memory from one block to another. i be anyway use `HeapAlloc` only (and src code become more simply with this too)

Comment: @RbMm whatever. I updated my example. Personally, I wouldn't use the Heap functions directly to begin with, but that is the OP's choice. I'm done now.